# What is the appropriate method to compare two means if data is nonnormal, sample size is different and variance seems equivalent?

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, levenes-test

I want to compare the means between groups `1` vs. `2` and also `2` vs. `3`. All three groups are nonnormal, as the Shapiro-Wilk test resulted in p values of 0.03, 0.04 and <0.0001 respectively. *n* is 10, 13 and 38 respectively, and the Levene test for equal variances resulted in p values of 0.22 for `1` vs. `2` and 0.44 for `2` vs. `3` (so they seem to have equal variances). Both, the parametric *t*-test and the nonparametric Wilcoxon test resulted in insignificant differences with p values larger than 0.5. Which test is more appropriate to this situation? The groups do not follow a normal distribution, have different sample size, but seem to be homoscedastic.
Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Mann-Whitney U (also called Wilcoxon rank sum) test is the nonparametric "equivalent" of the two sample t-test. Sounds like you did the right test(s).